# Pressing Enter in HTML5 type="tel" field not working on Android default browser

Tags: android, forms, html, tel

For some reason, when pressing enter on the default Android browser from within tel input fields, this will not submit the form.

Are there any known workarounds available?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to change the input type from tel into a normal text input box and then restrict what information can be entered with the pattern attribute ( http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp ).

This may be similar enough to act as a workaround, but you do lose the nice number entry keyboard.